# Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(array $data) must be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::create()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have an error Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(array $data) must be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::create() what can I do? Method 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::createtwo()' is not compatible with method 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller::createtwo()'.intelephense(1038)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:191|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function createtwo(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'username' => $data['username'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }
    public function createtwo()
    {
        return view('users.create');
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked one question, got an answer and then _completely_ rewrote the question to something _completely_ different? **Don't do that!** If the below answer solved it, accept it. If it didn't but you solved it yourself, either write an own answer and accept that. If you have more questions, post them as new posts. I've now rolled back the question to it's original so that the answer actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a php OOP (oriented object Programming) error. PHP simply tells you that the two createtwo() methods (the one of the "Controller" class and the one of the "RegisterController" class) are not compatible because your parent createtwo() method (the one of the "Controller" class) does not have a (array) $data parameter. Both methods must have the same declaration (prototype).

Answer (score -1):

```
class MainController extends Controller {
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function index() {   
        return view('index');
    }
}
```